# create a view from 3 different table

Tags: mysql

i'm looking for some help please, here is my situation.
i have three tables.

**table 1**

kpi_id , kpi_name, description_kpi

**table 2**

prog_id , prog_name, prog_description

**kpi_per_prog**

prog_id, kpi_id

now i want to creat a view from **kpi_per_prog** where i can have

**result_table**

id_prog , id_kpi, prog_name, kpi_name

kpi_id and prog_id are the primary keys

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
select r.prog_id , r.kpi_id from 
   result_table r join table1 t1 on (t1.kpi_id = r.kpi_Id) 
   join table2 t2 on (t2.prog_id = r.prog_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
CREATE VIEW KPIVIEW
SELECT 
    kpp.*, t2.prog_name, t1.kpi_name
FROM
    kpi_per_prog kpp
        LEFT JOIN
    table1 t1 ON kpp.kpi_id = t1.kpi_id
        LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON kpp.prog_id = t2.prog_id;
```